# how to get value by class name using javascript

Tags: javascript

Sorry, it's basic one but I trying to search on google anyways but still not get success.

I want get value of this

```
<input type='hidden' class='hid_id' value='1' />
```

**Using Javascript** I want alert value `1`

I trying this

```
var id = document.getElementsByClassName("hid_id");
alert (id);
```

But it's alert `[object HTMLInputElement]`

please help me now.

Answer (score 14):

getElementsByClassName() returns an array so you have to access first element (if there is any). Then try accessing value property:

```
var id = document.getElementsByClassName("hid_id");
if (id.length > 0) {
    alert (id[0].value);
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Keammoort/cd5cwvs5/)

Answer (score 9):

try this:

```
var id = document.getElementsByClassName("hid_id")[0].value;
```