# How to get value from particular element?

Tags: javascript, php

I need to take value, when click on particular link which has `id="username"` but it does not work...

My attempt:

```js
function rev() {
    var username = (this).getElementById("username").textContent;
    return alert (username);
}
```

```php
while($trackResultRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($trackResult)){?>

    <a onclick="rev()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down pull-right"></span></a>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up pull-right"></span>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $trackResultRow['track_path']?>"><span id="username"><?php echo $trackResultRow['username']?></span> - <span id="track"><?php echo $trackResultRow['track_name']?></span>

            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download pull-right"></span>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause pull-right" onclick="document.getElementById('aud').pause()"></span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play pull-right" onclick="document.getElementById('aud').play()"></span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <hr>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Also I tryed

```
function rev() {
   var username = document.getElementById(value).textContent;

   return alert (username);
}


 <button id="but" onclick="rev()">hey</button>
 <button id="but" onclick="rev()">hey233</button>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try without the `(this).`

Comment: One more time don't use duplicated id's. And if I understand you: var username = document.getElementById("usename").value;

Answer (score 1):

If you want to target an element on page, use `document.getElementById`

```
document.getElementById("username").textContent;
```

Comment: does not work it takes the value of first element only and it does not matter what element was clicked

Comment: I tryed to apply it to more simple example  <button id="but" onclick="rev()">hey</button>
                    <button id="but" onclick="rev()">hey233</button>......But the result in both cases is HEY

Comment: @PavelShilyaev You should only have one element with each ID.  IDs are meant to be unique; If you need multiple elements with the same selector, use classes instead. With multiple IDs, only the first one will ever be targeted.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for taking value from a html.

```
var value = document.getElementById('id').value;
```

If you want to get a specific value stored in a variable that is in your PHP code.

```
<input type = "text" id = "id" name = "var_PHP" value = "<?php echo $var_php;?>">
```

Comment: but I have different elements with the same id

Comment: Show me your html.

Comment: it is in the question

Comment: It is advisable that you do not have duplicate id's, you can have the same name but never the same id.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do,

1) Assign different ID to the each element found by  $trackResultRow['username'] by adding an incrementing variable like username_1, username_2  and then getElementById for each ID putting that in a for loop.

2) Assign a Class instead of ID and getElementsByClass and iterate through the result and get the value by using this
[how to get value by class name using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34207638/how-to-get-value-by-class-name-using-javascript)

getElementsById() will only give you first element.

Answer (score 0):

id in attribute tag html must different. Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<button id="items" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">Try it</button>
<button id="item" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">Try it again</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction(id) {
    var x = document.getElementById(id).textContent;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```