# Find span values with same class name from html string text value

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get data-mention-value of span classes with "dx-mention" in javascript or jquery?
sorry... it should be grabbed from html text string not from html page..

```html
<p>
  <span class="dx-mention" spellcheck="false" data-marker="@" data-mention-value="AgnesGan" data-id="AgnesGan">
    <span contenteditable="false">
      <span>@</span>
      AgnesGan
    </span>
  </span> 
  <span class="dx-mention" spellcheck="false" data-marker="@" data-mention-value="AK" data-id="AK">
    <span contenteditable="false">
      <span>@</span>AK
    </span>
  </span>
</p>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get value by class name using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34207638/how-to-get-value-by-class-name-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
$('.dx-mention').map(function() {
  return $(this).attr("data-mention-value")
}).get()
```

This will return both spans that is selected by the class, and get their data value.

**Demo**

```js
var string = `<p><span class="dx-mention" spellcheck="false" data-marker="@" data-mention-value="AgnesGan" data-id="AgnesGan"><span contenteditable="false"><span>@</span>AgnesGan</span>
  </span> <span class="dx-mention" spellcheck="false" data-marker="@" data-mention-value="AK" data-id="AK"><span contenteditable="false"><span>@</span>AK</span>
  </span>
</p>`

var log = $('.dx-mention', string).map(function() {
  return $(this).attr("data-mention-value")
}).get()
console.log(log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: sorry... it should be grabbed from html text string not from html page..

Comment: You have shown us html and not any indication about it's a string. @JaRoi Look at my demo, updated with string

Answer (score 1):

Access the [dataset property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) for each span with the `dx-mention` class. Use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to pick up the span elements, and then iterate over them.

`dataset` will return an object. However, because of the way hyphenated attributes are treated you need to target `mentionValue` rather than `mention-value`.

```js
const spans = document.querySelectorAll('.dx-mention');

spans.forEach(span => {
  console.log(span.dataset);
  console.log(span.dataset.mentionValue);
});
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="dx-mention" spellcheck="false" data-marker="@" data-mention-value="AgnesGan" data-id="AgnesGan">
<span contenteditable="false">
<span>@</span>AgnesGan</span>
  </span>
  <span class="dx-mention" spellcheck="false" data-marker="@" data-mention-value="AK" data-id="AK">
<span contenteditable="false">
<span>@</span>AK</span>
  </span>
</p>
```

Comment: sorry... it should be grabbed from html text string not from html page..

Comment: [Parse the string into an HTML document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser). The same process applies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following statement

```
document.querySelector('span.dx-mention').getAttribute('data-mention-value')
```

if you have multiple "span" elements you can use querySelectorAll and loop the nodes returned by the method.

Comment: sorry... it should be grabbed from html text string not from html page..

Comment: Ohh then you can create a temporary element with and append you html text inside that using innerHTML that and can perform the operation using element. querySelectorAll